# Error using bibtex file for bibliography

Tags: bibtex, natbib

when I compile my file, I receive the following error. what say this error?

Reason: No such file or directory C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\farsitex\config\miktex.ini: 
cannot read personal configuration note: there is no fndb for  C:\Local TeXMF note: there is no fndb for C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX

```
\documentclass[papera4]{article}‎

‎\usepackage[round]{natbib}‎

\begin{document}
matrix
‎
it is ‎\cite{esmailzadeh2011new} ‎and ‎‎\cite{ghosh1980main}‎‎
‎‎
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}‎
‎\bibliography{reference}‎

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you able to compile anything at all? Has your MikTeX distribution worked so far?

Comment: The option of `\documentclass` should be `a4paper`. Did you try refreshing the FNDB?

Comment: @Bernard Thank you very much. What is FNDB? when I write `bibitem` the file is compiled without any error, but when I use bibtex I receive error.

Comment: The `File Names DataBase`. You can refresh it with `MiKTeX Settings`.

Comment: @Bernard  How can I do it, please?

Comment: Under Windows 7, you have a shortcut in the `Start menu`.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you. I did it but the error have not been removed.

Comment: Can you post the .log file when you compile?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50992/discussion-between-fahim-b-and-bernard).